# Tableau -Calculated field for matching values based on criteria in a different column

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculated field based on three conditions .

I have two columns names " source system names"  which has only two values 302 and 202 only and other column name "unique ID have different numerical values .

I want to create a calculated field which will display the data as shown in "calculated field display " column. I need some help to write a logic on this .I have not done something like this before in tableau .Can someone help me out .I have around 0.5 million rows so need a logic that would work for this size of data .

Please refer attach image for a clear picture of what iam doing .

202 RECORD ONLY - when unique ID does not exists in row having source system as 302 .(example row 1,3 and 4)

302 RECORD ONLY - When  unique ID does not exists in row having source system as 202.(example row 9,11 and 12)

EXISTS in both 302 and 202 - when unique ID is same for source system names 302 and 202 .(2 and 10 , 5 and 8 and 6 and 7)

Kindly help me to create a calculated field with this logic .

I tried CASE and IF function ,but i was not able to do it .

for easy understanding refer the 4th column in the attached image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCmF3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'Source System Names' has only 2 values you could create the following calculations to do what you want (assuming all the fields are strings, if they're integers this will still work with some simple changes):

Max: Source System Name

```
{FIXED [Unique ID]: MAX([Source System Names])}
```

Min: Source System Name

```
{FIXED [Unique ID]: MIN([Source System Names])}
```

Calculated Field Display

```
IF [Min: Source System Name] != [Max: Source System Name]
    THEN 'Exists in Both 302 and 202'
ELSEIF [Max: Source System Name] = '202'
    THEN 'Exists in 202'
ELSEIF [Max: Source System Name] = '302'
    THEN 'Exists in 302'
ELSE
    NULL
END
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I just found that the source system has null values as well -so its 202 ,302 and null..I want to ignore the nulls .Also i tried ruining the above query i got an syntax error .Please advice .I am new to tableau .

Comment: If you want to ignore nulls, you can drag [Source System Name] to the Filters card and select only 202 and 302, but the calculation should still work even in the case where there is a null value for [Source System Name]. What's the syntax error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for your repose .Do i need to copy paste the whole code ?Currently i am coping the whole code but i get an operator missing syntax at end of  " Max: (here ) .Tableau 10 is suggesting me to replace it with MAX() instead of Max:. please advice what is wrong here .I think iam doing it wrongly .Let me know .

Comment: Just to clarify : I am coping all of the below code :                                         Max: Source System Name

{FIXED [Unique ID]: MAX([Source System Names])}
Min: Source System Name

{FIXED [Unique ID]: MIN([Source System Names])}
Calculated Field Display

IF [Min: Source System Name] = [Max: Source System Name]
    THEN 'Exists in Both 302 and 202'
ELSEIF [Max: Source System Name] = '202'
    THEN 'Exists in 202'
ELSEIF [Max: Source System Name] = '302'
    THEN 'Exists in 302'
ELSE
    NULL
END

Comment: So you need to create three separate calculated fields. At the top of Tableau, go to 'Analysis' > 'Create Calculated Field', and copy the code from the first snippet. Paste it in the window, and name the calculation 'Max: Source System Name'. Repeat for the other two code snippets in my response.

In the code for the first two calculations I provided, replace [Source System Names] with the name of the field in your data source that has the 202 and 302 data in it.

Comment: Hi ,I am getting 3 columns with "exists in both " , "exists in 202" and "null" ..the third one "exist in 302" is missing .I think the third IF else for 302 did not work. I checked few records and i see there are records with these combination .Can you see what went wrong in the code .Thank for helping .

Comment: Just updated my code, you were right! The new code should work now!

Comment: Thanks a lot . i have a clarification in calculated field display : we have two else if statements and both have "[Max: Source System Name] " .Should one of these should be [min:Source system Name ].Correct me if iam wrong ?

Comment: Since the first IF statement is checking for inequality between Max: Source and Min: Source, the ELSEIF statements will only be reached under two circumstances:

1) If Max: Source and Min: Source are equal, in which case it doesn't matter if we use Max or Min

2) Both Min and Max are NULL, which means that neither ELSEIF matters, and the function returns NULL